# Powershell: Change file attributes automatically when copying

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a folder of read only files. When I copy one of these files to a test location, I want to be able to copy them and not retain their original attributes.

I can do this, but this is lengthy.

```
copy-item srcfilefullname destfilefullname
set-itemproperty destfilefullname -isreadonly $false
```

I did not find anything in the documentation for copy-item. I am hoping there is a shorter way.

Thanks
Steeluser

Comment: PowerShell 3.0 changes the syntax slightly. No dash before isreadonly. eg. `Set-ItemProperty destfilefullname IsReadOnly $false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intention is not very clear. If you want to build a one-liner from that, try this (NOT TESTED):

```
copy-item srcfilefullname (set-itemproperty srcfilefullname -isreadonly $false -passthru).fullname
```

`PassThru` parameter allows `Set-ItemProperty` to generate and return a `PSCustomObject`.

Comment: I am creating a test bed of files in a folder Static. These are zero byte ReadOnly files. I need to copy any one of them into a testing-area folder where I should be free to manipulate these files. Hence the need to remove the readonly attribute from them when it is copied. Sure the one-liner is good; what I really wanted to know is if there is switch in the copy-item itself to do this automatically for us. Also can you please let me know what -passthru does?

Comment: No, I do not see any switch which does what you want. See [copy-item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347638.aspx). You can also read there what `PassThru` does: allows `set-itemproperty` to return the item being modified.