# Powershell Copy-Item -force doesn't preserve invisible folders

Tags: powershell, hidden

I've always used this simple piece of code to copy entire folder structure including invisible files/folders

```
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $dest -Recurse -Force;
```

It works but makes all hidden files/folders visible, basically the `Mode` property changes from `d--h-` to `d----`

```
# Source folder (hidden)
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                           
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                           
d--h-        04.09.2014     11:03            AppData   

# Destination folder (not hidden)
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                           
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                           
d----        04.09.2014     15:35            AppData
```

Is there a simple method to copy hidden folders as they are or do I need to iterate over each copied item and eventually make it invisible?

Comment: This is related, using Pass-through and `Get-ItemProperty` and `Set-ItemProperty` you should be able to piece it together: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5925846/736079

Comment: This has been logged here https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13552